# undefined index notice: Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my php code that is driving me nuts. I am getting an undefined index notice on this line: `echo " <input type=\"text\" name=\"column3\" value=\"".$row['hca']."\"/>\n";`. It seems to be a seemingly random error occuring. What is befuddling me is that the form code to display the data is exactly the same as the previous line and the line after, yet this snippet gets an error/notice. On top of this, the data is not being displayed from the database like it should, even though I have queried the database on the backend and found that the data is indeed there. Why is this occuring and what can I do to fix it? My code is below:

```
if ($count !== 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<div class=\"addform\"><form method='get' action=\"update.php\">\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"text\" value=\"".$row['tfid']."\" name=\"column1\">\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column2\" value=\"".$row['fname']."\"/>\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column3\" value=\"".$row['lname']."\"/>\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column3\" value=\"".$row['hha']."\"/>\n"; //there are issues here.
            echo "  <input type=\"text\" name=\"column5\" value=\"".$row['file']."\"/>\n";
            echo "  <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/update.png\" alt=\"Update Row\" class=\"update\" title=\"Update Row\">\n";
            echo "<a href=\"delete.php?column1=".$row['tfid']."\"><img title='Delete Row' alt=\"Delete\" class='del' src='images/delete.png'/></a></form></div>\n";
        }
    echo "</table><br />\n";
} else {
    echo "<b><center>NO DATA</center></b>\n";
}
```

Any tips that people could provide would be helpful.

thanks,
John

Comment: I don't see that line in your code. There are two lines with `name="column3"` (duplicating names in a form doesn't make sense), and one of them has `$row['lname']` and the other has `$row['hha']`. Make sure the index in `$row` matches the column you're retrieving from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Check the database and make sure that the fields names match the index of the array (`$row`).

Your table should have all this fields: `tfid`, `fname`, `lname`, `hha`, `file` and `tfid`

Also, escaping and PHP/echo/HMTL could led to visual noise, maybe this make your code easier to debug:

```
<?php if ($count !== 0) : ?>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
        <div class="addform">
            <form method="get" action="update.php">
                <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['tfid'] ?>" name="column1">
                <input type="text" name="column2" value="<?php echo $row['fname'] ?>"/>
                <input type="text" name="column3" value="<?php echo $row['lname'] ?>"/>
                <input type="text" name="column3" value="<?php echo $row['hha'] ?>"/>
                <input type="text" name="column5" value="<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"/>
                <input type="image" src="images/update.png" alt="Update Row" class="update" title="Update Row">;
                <a href="delete.php?column1=<?php echo $row['tfid'] ?>">
                    <img title="Delete Row" alt="Delete" class="del" src="images/delete.png"/>
                </a>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <b><center>NO DATA</center></b>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: `\n` doesn't work in single quotes. Better to use double quotes for the PHP strings, and single quotes for the HTML attributes.